# Workbook opening automatically on pressing Delete & Backspace Key - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have used Application.Onkey Key method to capture the pressing of Delete & Backspace Keys for my VBA project. This was done to provide access to users to delete the contents of certain cells in a protected worksheet.

The issue I am facing now is, even when the above said workbook is not currently opened, when the user presses Delete / Backspace Keys in other workbooks it causes the above said VBA workbook to open automatically.
I tried setting Application.enableevents = False in workbook_open() event in the VBA project, but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Code I used so far,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.OnKey Key:="{DEL}", Procedure:="DoSomething"
    Application.OnKey Key:="{BACKSPACE}", Procedure:="DoSomething"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
       Application.OnKey Key:="{DEL}"
       Application.OnKey Key:="{BACKSPACE}
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething()

Application.enableevents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set selectionrangefordeletion = Selection
If ActiveSheet.Name = ("Design-HW") Then
    rowposition = 4
        If worksheets("Design-HW").Cells(rowposition + 1, selectionrangefordeletion.Column).Value = "Target date" Or _
            worksheets("Design-HW").Cells(rowposition + 1, selectionrangefordeletion.Column).Value = "Actual date" Then
            If worksheets("Design-HW").Cells(selectionrangefordeletion.Row, selectionrangefordeletion.Column).Value <> "" Then
                previousdate1 = worksheets("Design-HW").Cells(selectionrangefordeletion.Row, selectionrangefordeletion.Column).Value
                selectionrangefordeletion.ClearContents
            End If
        End If
End If
```

Comment: If the sheet is active when the workbook closes, the worksheet_deactivate code never runs. Same with worksheet_activate when it is opened.

I suggest moving the code to Workbook_Open and Workbook_BeforeClose

Comment: @Toddleson. Thanks. But i already have code in the Workbook_Open and Workbook_Before close events. I cant move the code under the DoSomething module. Is there any other way

Comment: You can put multiple things into workbook_open and workbook_beforeclose and have an if statement to determine if they are meant to run. I think that would get you the intended interaction. Your users would no longer have the OnKey event firing after the workbook has closed.

Comment: Thank you. Issue is solved now. Have to do some more tests. I think the solution you provided will do fine.